# batch command inside python virtual env

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a .bat script that does

```
cd documents/code/project
env/scripts/activate.bat
```

but one is there, as expected, the path is not

C:\Users\User\Documents\Code\Project>

but

(env) C:\Users\User\Documents\Code\Project>

So, for example, if I add other command to the batch script it won't get it because the virtual environment is not accessible

let's supose I just want to change directory but with the environment already active. i.e.

```
cd documents/code/project
env/scripts/activate.bat
cd folderInProject
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just call `%HOME%\Documents\Code\Project\env\scripts\activate.bat` directly?

Comment: Also, there is no difference between `C:\Users\User\Documents\Code\Project>` and `(env) C:\Users\User\Documents\Code\Project>`. It's only the prompt being different, not the directory. `(env)` just means the virtual environment called `env` has been activated.

Comment: Change ```cd documents/code/project``` to ```CD "documents\code\project"```, and ```env/scripts/activate.bat``` to ```Call "env\scripts\activate.bat"```. And in future please use the search facility, there are thousands of examples showing the use of backward slashes for Windows paths, and the need to use `Call` to run one batch file from another, and returning to the initiating script whilst maintaining its environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Compo, @MattDMo for your comments, they opened my mind a lot and I'll have to study.

The solution is:

```
CD "documents\code\project"
Call "env\scripts\activate.bat"
CD "src"
```

but actually what I was looking was:

```
CD "documents\code\project"
Call "env\scripts\activate.bat"
Call python test.py
```

Just wanted to know how to be able to send batch commands once the env was already active.

Comment: Whilst it's good that you've provided feedback to the community, because the solution has been posted many times before, what you should have done was to simply thank me for giving you the answer, as a tagged comment, _(instead of not acknowledging it at all)_, and then deleted your question. However you should note, that `Call` is only for running a batch file from another batch file, it does not therefore belong on your last line, in the second code snippet you submitted above.

Comment: I voted up your comment, looked for the way to tag it but didn't find it. Thanks again